# Inoremap not working

Tags: unix, vim

I'm trying to set up auto bracket inserts in vim, and have done the following:

`:inoremap { {}<Left>`

But, when I go to insert mode, and enter `{`, only the `{` is inserted as expected. I have checked `:imap` and it contains the following:

```
i  <S-Tab>     * <C-R>=BackwardsSnippet()<CR>
i  <Plug>SuperTabBackward & <C-R>=SuperTab('p')<CR>
i  <Plug>SuperTabForward & <C-R>=SuperTab('n')<CR>
i  <C-Tab>     * <Tab>
i  <Tab>       * <C-R>=TriggerSnippet()<CR>
i  <CR>        * <C-R>=<SNR>19_SelectCompletion(1)<CR>
i  <C-R><Tab>  * <C-R>=ShowAvailableSnips()<CR>
i  <C-X>         <C-R>=<SNR>19_ManualCompletionEnter()<CR>
i  {}          * {}
i  {{          * {
i  {<CR>       * {<CR>}<Esc>O
i  {           * {}<Left>
```

Which shows it is set up correctly. Anyone able to help?

Comment: Well, it works alright for me, both the mapping in `:imap` and the insertion of right brackets when a left bracket is entered. I'm using `Vim 7.4.86`. What version are you using?

Comment: @Rubens I'm using Vim 7.2

Comment: Do the other mappings (e.g. `{<CR>`) work?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat Well I just removed all of the plugins to determine if that is the issue, so I only have the last 4 mappings in there now. No nothing is working for some reason, although if I do `:map <CR> :echo 'Hello'` that works correctly.

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with my .vimrc. I just ran vim -u NONE and the imaps are working correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the `<` value has been added to your `'cpoptions'`, so special key codes like `<Left>` don't work.
Watch out for `:set cpo` commands or `:set compatible` (which also affects `'cpo'`) in your `~/.vimrc`.

Also, don't `:set paste` in your `~/.vimrc`:

> When the 'paste' option is switched on (also when it was already on):
>         - mapping in Insert mode and Command-line mode is disabled

Rather, define a key to toggle this:

```
:set pastetoggle=<F11>
```

Comment: When I removed `set paste` from my `.bashrc` It worked strangely enough.

Comment: You mean .vimrc, right?! That's a problem, too. I've added that (and a fix) to my answer.

Comment: I also removed "set paste" and now works perfectly. Thaks so much for this hint.

Comment: This was bothering me since ages, and did not have a clue why. Hope someone can improve error handling one day :)
"set paste" is not far related to imap and its behavior. I wonder how you discovered this.